# Increasing quotas of Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I recently bought a web platform that uses Google Maps API, however the maximum quota set by Google is not enough for my need.

My account already has a credit card for billing. I have not found any option that I can modify this fast.

In Google developer there is only form, but so far no one answered me.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your billing for Google Maps via [this page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/?apis=maps). You will also want to make sure that your app is using the Maps API key for your account.